# Link to google maps in android app

Tags: android, google-maps, cordova

I am working on an app using phonegap. In one portion of the app I link to different google maps of businesses. The links work on iOS but when I test the app on android the links to google maps don't go anywhere.

When I click the a link the log shows: Refused to display document because display forbidden by X-Frame-Options.

Any help would be appreciated!